# Como retornar mais do que um valor usando uma AsyncTask em android?

Tags: android, return, asynctask

Resumidamente, a minha classe que extende uma AsyncTask, faz o download de uma série de dados do tipo byte, de seguida preciso de efectuar alguns cálculos com esses dados, e finalmente retornar todos estes valores para a minha MainActivity.

O código resume-se a:

```
class DataDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, byte[]> {

private String url;
private Context context;
private static byte[] data;

//--------------------CONSTRUCTOR--------------------------------//
public DataDownloaderTask(Context context) {
    this.data = null;
    this.context = context;
}

//--------------BACKGROUND---------------------------------------//
@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    return downloadData(params[0]);
}

//--------------POST EXECUTE-------------------------------------//
@Override
// Once the image is downloaded
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] data) {
    if(data != null){
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"Operação concluida com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"O ficheiro nao existe ou ocorreu um erro de conexão!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

o método que faz o download dos dados:

```
static Bitmap downloadData(String url) {

   //Download the data from url...

   //Calculate other values...
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 1;
   double value 3 = 0.1;

   //COMO RETORNAR OS DADOS: value1 value2 value 3 ...?

   return data;
}
```

na minha MainActivity tenho um método que faz isto:

```
DataDownloaderTask object = new DataDownloaderTask(MainActivity.this);
object.execute(string);

    try {
        mydata = object.get(); //mydata é to tipo byte[]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Portanto, gostaria de saber como posso obter na minha classe MainActivity, para além do array de bytes "data", outros valores de diferentes tipos calculados nessa mesma AsyncTask. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um método só retorna um tipo de dados, no entanto, esse tipo não precisa necessariamente de ser um tipo *simples* como *int*, *String*, *boolean*, etc.
Assim, quando se quer retornar um conjunto de dados, usa-se uma classe.

Escreva uma classe que tenha como atributos os dados que quer retornar:

```
public class MeusDados{
    private int mValue1;
    private int mValue2;
    private double mValue3;
    private byte[] mData;

    public MeusDados(int value1, int value2, double value3, byte[] data){
        mValue1 = value1;
        mValue2 = value2;
        mValue3 = value3;
        mData = data;
    }

    public int getValue1(){
        return mValue1;
    }

    public int getValue2(){
        return mValue2;
    }
    public double getValue3(){
        return mValue3;
    }
    public byte[] getData(){
        return mData;
    }
}
```

Declare a *AsyncTask* de forma a que o tipo que o método `doInBackground()` retorne seja essa classe:

```
class DataDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MeusDados> {

    .....
    .....
}
```

O método `doInBackground()` é declarado da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected MeusDados doInBackground(String... params) {
    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    return downloadData(params[0]);
}
```

No método `downLoadData()` crie uma objecto do tipo *MeusDados* passando ao construtor o `byte[]` e os dados calculados:

```
static MeusDados downloadData(String url) {

   //Download the data from url...
   byte[] data = //ler do url

   //Calculate other values...
   int value1 = 0;
   int value2 = 1;
   double value3 = 0.1;

   //Criar objecto MeusDados
   MeusDados dados = new MeusDados(value1, value2, value3, data);
   //Retornar o conjunto de dados
   return dados;
}
```

No método `onPostExecute()` receba esse conjunto de dados:

```
@Override
// Once the image is downloaded
protected void onPostExecute(MeusDados dados) {
    if(dados.getData != null){
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"Operação concluida com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(this.context,"O ficheiro nao existe ou ocorreu um erro de conexão!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :D