# Enviar e Retornar variáveis de uma asyncTask em classe java separada

Tags: java, asynctask, backgroundworker

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que consiste inserir variáveis, processá-las através de uma AsyncTask em classe java separada chamada backgroundWorker e retornar valores, conforme o desenho abaixo:

[image: Fluxograma mainsactivity asynctask]

Eu sei que é possível fazer isto na própria MainActivity, mas eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de processar os dados na backgroundWorker separada e retornar somente os resultados para a MainActivity?

Tenho um código que fiz até o momento, pesquisei mas não encontrei uma forma de enviar mais de um return.

MainActivity.java

```java
public void lerbground(){
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);

String pais = "Brasil"; 
int peso = 90; 
double altura = 1.81;
boolean estudante = true; 

backgroundWorker.execute(pais, peso, altura, estudante);
}
```

backgroundWorker.java

```java
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;

    String result_nacionalidade = null;
    String result_peso = null;
    String result_altura = null;
    String result_estudante = null;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {context = ctx;}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String pais = params[0];
    int peso = params[1];
    double altura = params[2];
    boolean estudante = params[3];


//VERIFICAÇÃO DE DADOS 1
if (pais == "Brasil") {
    result_nacionalidade = "nacional";
}
else{
    result_nacionalidade = "estrangeiro";
}

//VERIFICAÇÃO DE DADOS 2
if (peso >= 70) {
    result_peso = "pesado";
}
else{
    result_peso = "leve";
}

//VERIFICAÇÃO DE DADOS 3
if (altura >= 1.70) {
    result_altura = "alto";
}
else{
    result_altura = "baixo";
}

//VERIFICAÇÃO DE DADOS 4
if (estudante) {
    result_estudante = "é estudante";
}
else{
    result_estudante = "não estudante";
}

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);

//GOSTARIA QUE a backgroundWorker conseguisse enviar e que a MainActivity conseguisse receber os resultados:

//result_nacionalidade
//result_peso
//result_altura
//result_estudante

         }
    }

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Outra coisa que tenho dúvidas é se estaria correta a forma como eu parametrizei as variáveis?
[image: Inserçao de variaveis na asynctask]

Desde já agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Se não consegue retornar os campos separados, junte-os todos em um objeto e retorne esse objeto.

Comment: @Piovezan, obrigado pela resposta entendi. Mas aí, após isto, se eu quiser separar o objeto na MainActivity, somente será possível através de tratamento de string?

Comment: Veja [Como retornar mais do que um valor usando uma AsyncTask em android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70428/2541).